# Create table errors

Tags: database

I got an error when I created a table after logging in user Scott, I checked my syntax and cannot find where's error. I attached my screenshot as below. Please help, thanks.

@update code that I used to create table here, I tried to add ";" after create table but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(
       CUST_CODE         VARCHAR2(3 CHAR)  NOT NULL ,
       NAME      VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)  NOT NULL ,
       REGION            VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)  NOT NULL
)
       TABLESPACE USER5
       LOGGING
       PCTFREE 10
       INITRANS 20;
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: I tried to add that but still give same errors

Comment: Update your question with reproducible actual code that someone else can use.

Comment: You need to give the error message in order for people to be able to help you.  Also, version/type of database.

Comment: You should probably use `VARCHAR2(3)`, `VARCHAR2(50)`, etc. Never seen it used with the added `CHAR` keyword that you are using.

Comment: Appreciated your answer guys, I find my problem.